# Arduino Serial.println and initNode()

Tags: arduino, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS and am currently playing around with Arduino.
I came across this problem where after I initNode(), the output in serial monitor turns into backward question marks.

```
  void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    
    //nh.initNode();
    //nh.subscribe(sub);
    
    //myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
  }

    void loop() {
    Serial.println(15);//used for testing println
    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(100);
  }
```

if I comment nh.initNode() the serial monitor works fine. If I uncomment it, the serial monitor turns into backward question marks. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316805/arduino-serial.println-and-initnode()/) by [superkuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40236/superkuo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use `rosserial` and `Serial.println()` at the same time -- or at least: not with the same serial port.

`rosserial` must have (and assumes) exclusive use of the serial port it uses to communicate with your host. Otherwise it cannot work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [superkuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40236/superkuo/) on 2019-03-02**:
Thanks for the answer. That makes sense now!